# Position = "dodge" or "jitter" not working with geom_segments

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry for repost but I have a better working example of data that reflects my problem. I figured out how to supply custom colors that remain consistent even in the event of missing data (e.g. if Species in the below example omitted setosa, the colors should stay consistent). But now I'm unable to get the geom_segments to follow the "dodge" parameter. I've also tried "jitter" and even custom jittering using position_jitter(width=0.25).

```
colours <- c("#FF0000", "#33CC33", "#CCCCCC", "#FFA500", "#000000" )
iris$Month <- rep(seq(from=as.Date("2011-01-01"), to=as.Date("2011-10-01"), by="month"), 15)
d<-aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length, by=list(iris$Month, iris$Species), sum)
d$quota<-seq(from=2000, to=60000, by=2000)
colnames(d) <- c("Month", "Species", "Sepal.Width", "Quota")
d$Sepal.Width<-d$Sepal.Width * 1000
g1 <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=Month, y=Quota, color="Quota")) + geom_line(size=1)
g1 + geom_segment(data=d, mapping=aes(x=Month, y=0, ymax=Sepal.Width, yend=Sepal.Width, xend=Month, group=Species, color=Species, size=1), position="dodge") + scale_color_manual(values=colours)
```

The geom_segments are overlapping and I'd like them to be next to each other. Previously I just created each segment one by one with their own layers and offset the x-axis (Month + 5, Month + 10, etc.). But I wasn't able to get the custom colors for each line that way.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jitter or dodge geom_segments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002163/jitter-or-dodge-geom-segments)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a bar plot out of line segments... why not use `geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')`?  I'm having trouble picturing what you're trying to do if that isnt it.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick. Joran, I mentioned above that it's a duplicate as I had a cleaner example to start from. Add it as a solution and I'll mark as answer.

Comment: Reposting questions is frowned upon, and duplicates should (and will) be closed. I can't rescind my close vote here, but you should not keep both copies around. Please delete the other version, and in the future, only edit, don't repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to make a bar plot out of line segments... instead use:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=Month, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```